# How to config htaccess to html can execute php

Tags: .htaccess, config

I want to configure the htaccess file to execute php file in html, but I get an error 500 Internal Server.

this here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

 AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

</IfModule>
```

Comment: did you tried restarting apache?

Comment: thank you for help, i just rename my html file, the problem is solved